# VBA Incrementing Numbers with Different Words and Dates

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm new to programming and vba. I want to generate an **incrementing numbers base on the year and account code**. for example "TES1-2023-OE-01-001", and when I want to add another item with the same year and account code it will increment but when it is different year or account code, it will generate a new number starting 001. So far `a, b, c, d variables` are working fine but the last number stays 0. Here's my code below. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub FindPropertyNum()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserForm1")
    If Range("D4").Value = Empty Then 'D4 is where they can select the account code
        Exit Sub
    End If
'Check Account Code
    CheckAccCode 'Variable c - OE,ICT,CE,FFE,ME,TSE,DRRE,OSM,OPPE,SE,PE

a = "TES1"
b = Right(Range("D6").Value, 4) 'YEAR
d = Left(Range("D6").Value, 2) 'MONTH

myProp = UCase(a & "-" & b & "-" & c & "-" & d & "-")

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 15 To lr
        If ws.Cells(x, 7) = myProp Then 'Column 7 is where the incrementing numbers are stored
        lastnum = (ws.Cells(x, 7)

    Stop
        lastnum = Format(lastnum + 1, "000#")

         End If
    Next x
Range("E2").Value = myProp & lastnum
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: yes. lr = last row value. It loops just fine. I think what I am missing here is the proper coding to get the right 'if statement' and also to increment the numbers

Comment: yes that's for variable c

Comment: You could also just `Split` it using the dash as a delimiter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function and then look at each piece by an index number, and then each piece could be any length.